How to manipulate data from an Elementor Pro form and save it in a hidden field?
everything good? I have a WordPress site with Elementor Pro installed and I have been trying unsuccessfully to manipulate the data of a form and save the result of this manipulation in a hidden field on the form itself. Specifically, I need to create a record that has the prefix EXC, followed by the person's first name and then the last four phone numbers. Ex: EXC Pedro 1234. The form has only 3 fields in addition to the hidden field. I've already tested 3 scripts but none worked, some with an error message after sending, others without an error message. In common, all were saved correctly, however, without the result of manipulation in the hidden field.
Could anyone help or guide me so that I can carry out this manipulation and recording? Thank you in advance!
The scripts used were the following:
add_action( 'elementor_pro/forms/new_record', function( $record, $handler ) {
    // Certifique-se de que o formulário é o "cap-avalanche"
    $form_name = $record->get_form_settings( 'form_name' );
    if ( 'cap-avalanche' !== $form_name ) {
        return;
    }

    $raw_fields = $record->get('fields');
    $fields = [];
    foreach ( $raw_fields as $id => $field ) {
        $fields[ $id ] = $field['value'];
    }

    // Manipulação dos dados
    if ( ! empty( $fields['name'] ) && ! empty( $fields['field_3aa9bef'] ) ) {
        // Pega o primeiro nome
        $nome_array = explode(' ', trim($fields['name']));
        $primeiro_nome = $nome_array[0];

        // Pega os quatro últimos números do telefone
        $telefone = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $fields['field_3aa9bef']);
        if(strlen($telefone) >= 4) {
            $ultimos_quatro = substr($telefone, -4);
        } else {
            // Se o telefone tiver menos de 4 dígitos, usa o que estiver disponível
            $ultimos_quatro = $telefone;
        }

        // Cria o novo título
        $novo_titulo = 'FAD' . $primeiro_nome . $ultimos_quatro;

        // Atualiza o campo oculto 'titulo'
        $_POST['form_fields']['titulo'] = $novo_titulo;
    }
}, 10, 2 );


In the next script I changed the way the record is updated, according to the Elementor documentation:
add_action( 'elementor_pro/forms/new_record', function( $record, $handler ) {
    // Certifique-se de que o formulário é o "cap-avalanche"
    $form_name = $record->get_form_settings( 'form_name' );
    if ( 'cap-avalanche' !== $form_name ) {
        return;
    }

    $raw_fields = $record->get('fields');
    $fields = [];
    foreach ( $raw_fields as $id => $field ) {
        $fields[ $id ] = $field['value'];
    }

    // Manipulação dos dados
    if ( ! empty( $fields['name'] ) && ! empty( $fields['field_3aa9bef'] ) ) {
        // Pega o primeiro nome
        $nome_array = explode(' ', trim($fields['name']));
        $primeiro_nome = $nome_array[0];

        // Pega os quatro últimos números do telefone
        $telefone = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $fields['field_3aa9bef']);
        if(strlen($telefone) >= 4) {
            $ultimos_quatro = substr($telefone, -4);
        } else {
            // Se o telefone tiver menos de 4 dígitos, usa o que estiver disponível
            $ultimos_quatro = $telefone;
        }

        // Cria o novo título
        $novo_titulo = 'FAD' . $primeiro_nome . $ultimos_quatro;

        // Atualiza o campo oculto 'titulo'
        // Encontra o campo pelo seu ID e atualiza seu valor
        foreach ($record->get('fields') as $field_id => &$field) {
            if ('titulo' === $field_id) {
                $field['value'] = $novo_titulo;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    
    // Atualiza os dados do formulário com os novos valores dos campos
    $record->update_fields();
}, 10, 2 );



Can you post a sample of your input data and what you want in the output? If you add your form structure this may be helpful for targeting the elements.

Sure! The form has 4 fields:
Name ---> ID name ---> type text
Phone ---> ID field_3aa9bef ---> type text
E-mail ---> ID email ---> type email
Tituto ---> ID titulo ---> type hidden
I need fill the hidden field Titulo with the foward manipulation: add the prefix EXC, the first word of field Name and the last 4 numbers of the field Phone...
Name: Carl Sagan
Phone: 5555-5555
Email: irrelevant@thisissue.com
to
Titulo: EXC Carl 555

I see. You can not manipulate the form data in the client side. PHP is server side script language. But you can save the manipulated data to you database. If you still need to manipulate the data in client side before submitting, Use JavaScript. add a script to the form page.

Add this script bellow you form tag.
<script>
   const form = document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0]
   form.addEventListener('change', () => {
    console.log('form changed')
        let name = document.getElementsByName('name')[0].value.split(' ')[0];
        let phone = document.getElementsByName('field_3aa9bef')[0].value;
        if(name && phone ){                
            let ext = phone.match(/\s[0-9]+$/);
            document.getElementsByName('titulo')[0].value = ('EXT: ' + name + ' ' + ext);
        }
    });

</script>

